# Using mlab, with Meteor, and deploying to Galaxy: Receiving error "not authorized on" DB "to execute command"

Tags: database, meteor, authorization, mlab, galaxy

Using mlab, with Meteor, and deploying to Galaxy, I am receiving error `"not authorized on <DB> to execute command"`.

This error started when I accidentally deleted the database user I was using to log in. I re-created the user. I made sure my account user had the same username and password. The database user has the following credentials:

```
{
    "_id": "db.username",
    "user": "username",
    "db": "password",
    "roles": [
        {
            "role": "dbOwner",
            "db": "db"
        }
    ]
}
```

My settings url has not changed:

```
mongodb://username:password@ds115758.mlab.com:15758/db
```

What am I doing wrong? This is driving me crazy :(

Error:

```
Exception in setInterval callback: MongoError: not authorized on db to execute command { delete: "meteor_oauth_pendingRequestTokens", ordered: true, $db: "db" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Reach out to **support@mlab.com**. They are super helpful and helped me debug and fix my issue.

In case it's helpful, the ongoing authentication issues were due to my Galaxy app not closing and re-opening connections following the removal of the database user. I've included some log messages below showing this behavior:

```
2018-10-22T05:00:00.798-0700 I COMMAND  [conn616856] command db.dbname command: insert { insert: "dbname", ordered: true, $db: "db" } ninserted:1 keysInserted:1 numYields:0 reslen:229 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2, w: 2 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { w: 2 }, acquireWaitCount: { w: 1 }, timeAcquiringMicros: { w: 46 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 2 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { W: 1 } }, Metadata: { acquireCount: { W: 1 } }, oplog: { acquireCount: { W: 1 } } } protocol:op_query 182ms

2018-10-22T23:15:34.155-0700 I ACCESS   [conn616856] Removed deleted user dbusername@db from session cache of user information.

2018-10-22T23:15:34.155-0700 I ACCESS   [conn616856] Unauthorized: not authorized on db to execute command { find: "meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration", filter: {}, projection: { secret: 0 }, $db: "db" }
```

From yesterday, when the user was removed:

```
2018-10-22T05:00:00.798-0700 I COMMAND  [conn616856] command db.dbname command: insert { insert: "dbname", ordered: true, $db: "db" } ninserted:1 keysInserted:1 numYields:0 reslen:229 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2, w: 2 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { w: 2 }, acquireWaitCount: { w: 1 }, timeAcquiringMicros: { w: 46 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 2 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { W: 1 } }, Metadata: { acquireCount: { W: 1 } }, oplog: { acquireCount: { W: 1 } } } protocol:op_query 182ms

2018-10-22T23:15:34.155-0700 I ACCESS   [conn616856] Removed deleted user dbusername@db from session cache of user information.

2018-10-22T23:15:34.155-0700 I ACCESS   [conn616856] Unauthorized: not authorized on db to execute command { find: "meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration", filter: {}, projection: { secret: 0 }, $db: "db" }
```

From today; note how the not authorized messages have the same thread ID (conn616856):

```
2018-10-23T09:24:54.778-0700 I ACCESS   [conn616856] Unauthorized: not authorized on db to execute command { delete: "meteor_oauth_pendingCredentials", ordered: true, $db: "db" }
2018-10-23T09:27:54.785-0700 I ACCESS   [conn616856] Unauthorized: not authorized on db to execute command { delete: "meteor_oauth_pendingCredentials", ordered: true, $db: "db" }
2018-10-23T09:30:54.794-0700 I ACCESS   [conn616856] Unauthorized: not authorized on db to execute command { delete: "meteor_oauth_pendingCredentials", ordered: true, $db: "db" }
```

All of the existing connections lost their permissions' removed when the database user was removed. These connections either need to re-authenticate or new authenticated connections will need to be created.

I tried closing my connection and having it start again and it seems to be working better.

Denzil